# Force GC for spec on Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, garbage-collection, specifications

I'm working in a project when I will manage a lot objects created by a external C dll.
Now, I'm starting with my class Scope, which implement a patter for keep memory of other "releaseables" objects. So I need invoke a release method for every reference that Scope object will maintain, when the Scope object is destroyed.
This is my code:

```
module ServiceBus

  class Scope
    def initialize
      @releaseables = []

      ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, self.class.finalize(@releaseables))
    end

    def self.finalize(releaseables)
      proc { releaseables.each { |obj| obj.release } }
    end

    def add_obj(obj)
      raise "#{self.class} only support releasbles objects" unless obj.respond_to?(:release)
      @releaseables << obj
    end
  end
end
```

and my spec:

```
subject(:subject) { ServiceBus::Scope.new }

context "obj respons_to release" do
  let(:obj) do
    obj = double("ReleaseableObject")
    allow(obj).to receive(:release)

    obj
  end

  it "success" do
    subject.add_obj obj
  end

  it "call invoke for all added objects" do
    other_obj = double("ReleaseableObject")
    allow(other_obj).to receive(:release)

    subject.add_obj obj
    subject.add_obj other_obj

    subject = nil
    GC.start

    expect(other_obj).to have_received(:release)
    expect(other_obj).to have_received(:release)
  end
end
```

This is failing because the finalize never is execute before the expectations.
**How should I force the GC for destroy my subject object.**

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible. It is up to the specific Ruby implementation to decide if and when the objects are actually destroyed. Since garbage collection is implementation specific, no guarantees are made. This unfortunately means that the finalizers may never be called. However, I think the spec can as well just test the finalizer in isolation. In other words, when you trigger the GC manually, you might as well trigger the finalizer manually and test its effects.